# Как получить информацию о разделе loop / /dev/mapper/partition?

Tags: linux, c, диск

Язык - C, система - Linux, *BSD (пишу кросс-платформенную программу). Надо получить информацию о разделе (не диске, разделе). Знаю про libblkid, но там надо вначале получить информацию о целом диске (`sda`), а мне надо "в лоб" получить информацию о разделе (вида `/dev/loop0`, `/dev/dm-0`). Как это можно сделать, а то в libblkid я не нашёл функций, которые бы по пути раздела (`/dev/sda1`) выдавали о нем информацию...

Comment: У Вас в описании указан C, а в тегах - C++.

Comment: сейчас поправлю